# NFS client does not pick up server after restart

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, nfs, google-compute-engine

EDIT :

To summarize the issue, this is a problem with the NFS server changing IP address and the NFS clients not picking up the new address. I can see via `tcpdump` that the client still tries to contact the old IP address on port 2049.

We have several NFS mount points defined like this in `/etc/fstab`. As you can see, this is NFS v3.

```
storage-1:/data/medias/media /var/www/myproject/data/media nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,actimeo=300,nfsvers=3,async,noatime,sec=sys 0 0
storage-1:/data/medias/secure /var/www/myproject/web/secure nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,actimeo=300,nfsvers=3,async,noatime,sec=sys 0 0
storage-1:/data/tobeprocessed /var/www/myproject/data/tobeprocessed nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,actimeo=300,nfsvers=3,async,noatime,sec=sys 0 0
storage-1:/data/ftp /var/ftp nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,actimeo=300,nfsvers=3,async,noatime,sec=sys 0 0
```

When we restart the server, we have to unmount and remount each endpoint, otherwise the clients are unable to access the NFS server. I tried up to 5 minutes after the reboot before unmounting and remounting.

After a restart of the NFS server, a simple `ls /var/www/myproject/data/media` makes the console hang.

I can also see the following messages in `/var/log/syslog` :

```
Sep 16 11:24:36 encoder-1 kernel: [69688.160102] nfs: server storage-1 not responding, still trying
Sep 16 11:30:15 encoder-1 kernel: [70027.744042] nfs: server storage-1 not responding, still trying
```

When I `umount` and then `mount` one of the nfs directories on the client, I can then access it. But I cannot access the others unless I also `umount` and `mount` them.

I anyone knows a possible solution for this, I am all ears. Note that `rpcinfo` shows that the client is able to contact the server, as shown below.

There is one NFS server, 4 NFS clients for a total of 12 mount points.

The result of `rpcinfo -p storage-1` from a client :

```
[0]root@encoder-1:/var/log # rpcinfo -p storage-1
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  52115  status
    100024    1   tcp  57907  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  59603  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  59603  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  59603  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  47716  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  47716  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  47716  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp    892  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    2   udp    892  mountd
    100005    2   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    3   udp    892  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    892  mountd
```

When enabling NFS debug traces [as explained here](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/General_troubleshooting_recommendations), we get the following log message :

```
Sep 17 05:35:00 encoder-1 kernel: [135112.160230] nfs: server storage-1 not responding, still trying
Sep 17 05:53:47 encoder-1 kernel: [136240.018538] NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(///) is valid
Sep 17 05:53:47 encoder-1 kernel: [136240.018538] NFS: revalidating (0:12/5242881)
Sep 17 05:53:47 encoder-1 kernel: [136240.018538] NFS call  getattr
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for the question, I added that extra info in the original question. To answer here : There is one NFS server, 4 NFS clients for a total of 12 mount points. I waited 5 minutes after the server was up again, before unmounting and remounting. How long should I wait ?

Comment: I was thinking of the grace period in Solaris NFS daemons. That is usually within 1 minute. I guess your NFS server is also a Debian server.

Comment: Yes the NFS server is also Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be a problem resolving the hostname. I have noticed that even if resolving seems to work fine otherwise on the system and network the NFS mount processes appear to be occasionally having a problem with it. I would change the hostname to the actual IP address and try that out.Lets say the FQDN is storage-1.example.org and it would resolve to 192.0.2.11 then do:

```
192.0.2.11:/data/medias/media /var/www/myproject/data/media nfs bg,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,actimeo=300,nfsvers=3,async,noatime,sec=sys 0 0
```

Even if that doesn't fix the problem I personally find using the IP address instead of the hostname or FQDN to be preferable. But I understand there could be reasons why you wouldn't want to do that.

**Note**: I added the ***bg*** option, which will background the mount process in case it takes longer to mount, in order to speed up booting. It's up to you if you would prefer that. I thought I'd mention it since when there are a number of NFS mountpoints with each one taking longer (or timing out) to mount the boot time may easily become more than one hour.

Comment: That's very interesting feedback, unfortunately since the machines are hosted on Google Compute Engine, the internal IP address changes after each reboot and I cannot rely on it for the NFS setup. Because the NFS server's address will change on reboot, I am not even able to verify the DNS issue.

Comment: Actually, I was able to confirm your information using `tcpdump`. The NFS server changes IP but the NFS client does not pick this up and I can see attempts to contact the old server IP address. Thank you very much for leading me there !

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I was suspecting the FQDN might be pointing to variable IP addresses and thus using the IP address could be a problem. You could try and flush the dns cache before mounting happens so it may pick up the right IP address.